# How to fix "XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i have written this code and it says an error like this help me to solve this problem

i have already installed  `xlrd` 
and again using `pip install xlrd`

`import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
datas=pd.read_excel('transactions.xlsx')
datas`

and error shows like this

```
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-f7361e459a83> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import os
----> 4 datas=pd.read_excel('transactions.xlsx')
      5 datas

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, parse_cols, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skip_footer, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    348 
    349     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 350         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    351 
    352     return io.parse(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    651         self._io = _stringify_path(io)
    652 
--> 653         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    654 
    655     def __fspath__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    422             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    423         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, compat.string_types):
--> 424             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    425         else:
    426             raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    143         if 'content.xml' in component_names:
    144             raise XLRDError('Openoffice.org ODS file; not supported')
--> 145         raise XLRDError('ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook')
    146 
    147     from . import book

XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook
```

Comment: Did you try to load any other file with  the same extension ? Seems like something is wrong with this file.

Comment: thank you @Mikku i haven't tried that it worked :)

Comment: Glad it Worked :) .. Accept the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for users facing the Same Error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
datas=pd.read_excel('transactions.xlsx')
datas
```

This should work, unless there is something wrong with the Excel file. Try with other files with the same Extension.